# Debug tomEE on IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, apache-tomee

I know that this answer was asked before, but I couldn't find a clear solution from the given answers.

I want to debug a maven project that implements a web service on tomEE using IntelliJ or any other IDE.

I know that instead of calling the goal `tomee:run` I must call `tomee:debug`. And that's what I did:
In IntelliJ, I click on `Run / Edit Configurations` then `+`, I chosen `Maven`, I located the project directory and I set `tomee:debug`as command line. I started the debug and it says:

Started server process on port: 8080

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

I think this first step is correct. The second step as I understood is to create a remote configuration, and this is what I failed to do.

What I did is the following:
`Run / Edit Configurations`then `+`, then `TomEE Server`. Here I choose `local` or `remote`? In my case I think local because the project is local on the device and I call it using localhost:8080.

[image: tomee]

After that, how to configure this page? What will be the port number 5005 or 8080? And when I finish configuring this page what I do? Run or debug?

[image: tomee config]

I would appreciate a detailed answer because I was not able to understand the short answers given on other questions.

Comment: Since you start the server externally, you have to choose Remote. If you want IntelliJ IDEA to start TomEE for you instead of starting it from Maven, use Local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

**Step 1:**
 In IntelliJ, I click on `Run / Edit Configurations` then `+` to add a new configuration, I chosen `Maven`, I located the project directory and I set `tomee:debug`as command line. I started the debug and it says:

`Started server process on port: 8080`

`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`

An alternative solution can be by locating the project directory in terminal and running the command: `mvn tomee:debug`

**Step 2:** In IntelliJ, I click on `Run / Edit Configurations` then `+` to add a new configuration, I chosen `Remote`, and I specify `localhost` with port `5005`.

[image: remote]

Now I click `OK`, and I `debug` this configuration.

Breakpoints are detectable and debugging works perfect.